# Creating `multiprocessing.Pool` slow with high memory jobs

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-multiprocessing, python-3.9

Starting a  `multiprocessing.Pool` takes longer when the parent uses more memory, probably due to forking. I tried `get_context("spawn")` to create a `Pool` of empty python processes, but it didn't work - plus I wouldn't know how to apply *ad-hoc* / *on the spot* functions that can't be imported. I'm using notebooks for scientific computing, so these ad-hoc functions are essential for experimentation.

Yet somehow, `htop` doesn't show the memory actually being copied, since memory usage doesn't spike 40x each `Pool(40)`, which suggests some laziness or 'copy-on-write' behavior, but then it's still weird initializing the `Pool` takes so long.

How can I quickly get a Pool in notebooks with high memory that don't need access to the bulk?

```
import time
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool, get_context

without_x = get_context("spawn")

t0 = time.time()
with Pool(40) as pool:
  print(f'Initializing without data took {time.time() - t0:.2f}s')

t0 = time.time()
with without_x.Pool(40) as pool:
  print(f'Initializing spawn pool with data took  {time.time() - t0:.2f}s')

x = np.zeros(1024 ** 3, dtype=np.uint32)
x[:]=1

t0 = time.time()
with Pool(40) as pool:
  print(f'Initializing pool with 4GB data took {time.time() - t0:.2f}s')

t0 = time.time()
with without_x.Pool(40) as pool:
  print(f'Initializing spawn pool with 4GB data took {time.time() - t0:.2f}s')
```

Result:

```
Initializing without data took 0.33s
Initializing spawn pool with data took  0.21s
Initializing pool with 4GB data took 1.71s
Initializing spawn pool with 4GB data took 1.93s
```

## Update

@juanpa.arrivillaga 's suggestion to guard large memory allocation with `__name__ == "__main__"` doesn't seem to work (I restarted the process as well).

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
# if True:
  print('Initializing 4GB of data')
  x = np.zeros(1024 ** 3, dtype=np.uint32)
  x[:]=1

t0 = time.time()
with Pool(40) as pool:
  print(f'Initializing pool with 4GB data took {time.time() - t0:.2f}s')

t0 = time.time()
with without_x.Pool(40) as pool:
  print(f'Initializing spawn pool with 4GB data took {time.time() - t0:.2f}s')
```

Result:

```
Initializing 4GB of data
Initializing pool with 4GB data took 3.48s
Initializing spawn pool with 4GB data took 3.60s
```

Comment: only initialize the data in the master process, guard that initialization in an `if __name__ == "__main__": ...`

Comment: "plus I wouldn't know how to apply ad-hoc / on the spot functions that can't be imported. " That isn't standard terminology, so you really should elaborate on what you mean precisely

Comment: I mean functions defined in a notebook (.ipynb) cell, but not in a module (.py), so you can't import them from a path.

Comment: Note, just creating a pool isn't going to make 40 processes, that is just *the maximum number of processes allowed*. You'd have to start submitting jobs to the pool to see potentially 40 different processes

Comment: Can you use `__name__ == "__main__"` in ipython notebooks? How would `Pool(...)`'s fork know to not copy a variable that was created in such an if-clause? I'm assuming the whole process isn't rerun by each Worker, because that takes 10 minutes in my case, and starting up and using a Pool doen't take that long.

Comment: One addition, I also tried creating the pool at the start of the script, and reusing it all the time, but I noticed would become non-responsive after a while, e.g. `ApplyResult.get` would hang where it didn't hang before.